# GridView Footer row is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, footer

Footer is set to visible and I can see it's being created. However when total (table sums) are passed over to it, there's error indicating GridView2.FooterRow is null...
totTable refers to a DataTable carrying totals.

aspx:

```
ShowHeader="true" ShowFooter="true" FooterStyle-CssClass="FooterStyle"
```

cs:

```
 DataRow dr = totTable.Rows[0];
 foreach (DataControlField col in GridView2.Columns)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn dc in totTable.Columns)
                    {
                        int i = GridView2.Columns.IndexOf(col);
                        GridView2.FooterRow.Cells[i].Text = dr[i].ToString();

                    }
                }
```

What's the root cause behind this?

Comment: @Hyarantar oh yeah... dataTable Row.. let me edit the post.

Comment: Alright I managed to solve it. It's mainly due to the fact that GridView2 isn't *initialized* by the time I am trying to access the Footer.. so there you go...

Answer (score 0):

use following code after binding gridview:

```
    public void CountGrandTotal()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <grdproduct.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            Label lblprice = (Label)grdproduct.Rows[i].FindControl("Label5");

            sum += int.Parse(lblprice.Text);
        }
        Label lblgtotal = (Label)grdproduct.FooterRow.FindControl("Label7");
        lblgtotal.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: I am not sure if you had seen my last comment. I have gotten it solved. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Add the footer on the OnLoad method of the GridView.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="Gv"
  runat="server"     
  ShowFooter="true"
  OnLoad="Gv_Load">
```

Comment: just reposting your own answer @bonCodigo